# Live Wallpaper Scaling bitmap hundred of times at different positions

Tags: android, bitmap, live, wallpaper

I am making a live wallpaper app in android studio in which i need bubble effect like in this gif [image: bubble effect]

I am developing it naively i.e. no library. What I have tried is creating several hundred rect object and drawing bitmap with different destination rect as time passes. Problem with this approach is that I will have to create several thousands of rect objects to achieve this effect. Any Suggestion. I need this effect on touch.

Comment: Have a look at [This awesome blog](https://medium.com/@patrick_iv/continuous-animation-using-timeanimator-5b8a903603fb) see if this work out for you. Cause i do not have much idea a How LiveWallpaper works ..

Comment: you have `SurfaceHolder` so you can use its `lockCanvas()` method and draw whatever you want  - it does not have to be `Bitmap` only

Comment: pskink yes i am able to draw bitmaps, but as you can see i need to draw scalling bitmaps to achieve animation effect.

Comment: check [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) API documentation

Comment: pskink can you please tell me about some method which may be helpful?

Comment: for example `drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)`

Comment: pskink I have tried this method already. for this method i will have to create thousands of (rectf dst) objects as rect objects have fixed coordinates to draw but i need to draw at different places

Comment: `RectF#set`? why dont you read the official documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Matrix for scaling and for other things.